# Почему на вопросах, описывающих дефекты, так долго не появляются красные метки?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, мета

Вопрос можно сформулировать иначе:

> Стоит ли пинать модератора, если явный и легко проверяемый дефект не помечен одним из красных тегов в течение, допустим, пары дней?

Например, на текущий момент, как оказалось, я уже [запостил 87 сообщений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%5D%20user%3A176217%20is%3Aquestion) с тегом [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82). При этом [почти половина из них](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%5D%20user%3A176217%20is%3Aquestion%20-%5B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81*%5D) не имеет красных тегов `статус*`.

Не является ли такое поведение модераторов тормозом в развитии сообщества "Stack Overflow на русском"?

Answer (score 6):

Субъективно:

Из троих модераторов и одного менеджера сообщества только один я — тестировщик с лёгким ОКР. :) Я нервничаю, когда вижу неразмеченные багрепорты, поэтому обычно сразу пытаюсь воспроизвести и ставлю метку. А мои коллеги, разработчики и руководители, относятся к багрепортам куда спокойнее. Николас, по моим наблюдениям, ставит только [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), когда ошибка уже исправлена.

Почему не везде есть метки — много работы, нет сил везде ставить метки. :)

Если вы тоже нервничаете, кидайте ссылку в чат. ;)

Comment: Что такое “неразмеченный багрепорт”?

Comment: что такое ОКР? :-)

Comment: @Grundy это анаграмма к слову "орк".

Comment: @alexolut. "тестировщик с легким орк" не стало понятнее :)

Comment: @Grundy гуглите :) (на StackOverflow об этом не пишут)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, _Олимпийский комитет России (ОКР)_???? хм хм хм

Comment: Может дать права на эти метки тем, кто радеет за сайт? @alexolut отлично подходит.

Comment: @Other он может баллотироваться на следующих выборах модераторов (пока не планировались) или устроиться работать в Stack Exchange. :) Других способов нет.

Comment: Не верю что так уж сложно добавить кастомные права пользователю. Выборы будут **когда-то**, а дефекты есть **сейчас**.

Comment: Сложно или нет, никто не станет это запиливать только потому, что в одном сообществе метки не успевают развешивать.

Comment: @Nofate, разве у нас не автономное в данном смысле общество? Ведь если есть потребность, то стоит её сделать.

Comment: @Other нет, далеко не любая фича стоит того, чтобы её делать. У разработчиков есть приоритеты фич.

Comment: @Other самое главное: объясните, в чём проблема с тем, что какой-то дефект помечается меткой с опозданием? Мне видится, что вы решаете несуществующую проблему.

Comment: Проблема в том, что дефекты не то, чтобы оперативно решаются. Как мне кажется, это довольно существенная проблема чтобы ради неё создать новую должность.

Comment: @Other непереведённые строки может переводить каждый. Баги движка, включая локализацию, могут чинить только сотрудники-разработчики. Введение новой должности только отнимет у них время, которое может быть потрачено на починку багов.

Comment: Ладно, Вашу позицию я понял.

Comment: @NickVolynkin чтоб переводить строки нужен аккаунт transifex, а чтоб утверждать - ещё и доп. привилегии. Так что не совсем каждый. Проблема отсутствия меток в том, что создается впечатление будто найденный баг никому нафиг не нужен. Собственно активность на Мете вообще слабая по вопросам багов.